# Why does the bit count of a string output from a hashing function (SHA256) fluctuate?

Tags: encoding, hash, sha

I think I'm having a core misunderstanding about how bit counts of strings work and am hoping someone could clear it up for me.

I'm trying to determine the best SQL Server data type for storing a key derived from SHA256. The answers out there vary widely, and I want to really understand the topic before I go hastily implementing SO answers.

I made a [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/F9qVmy) to test out inspecting the length and bit count of various SHA256 hashes, but I'm getting inconsistent results. The number of bits fluctuates around 294-303, whereas I thought it should always be 256. Am I counting the bits wrong? Is my approach for verifying what SQL data type I need flawed? `char(32)` seems to make sense on paper (256 bits divided by 8 bits per character = 32), but the actual string length of the hash is coming out as 44, so I'm confused. Any insight will be appreciated.

Comment: The output of SHA256 is 256 bits, so you're not going crazy. But the output is an arbitrary 256-bit string that is not a valid sequence of characters under almost any character encoding. So, if you are not planning to store the output as some kind of binary value but rather as a "string" of characters then you must encoded the 256-bits into a valid "string". Common encoding methods include base64 and hex encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're counting the wrong bits. Your question actually is about your `GetBits()` method:

```
public static string GetBits(string input)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (byte b in Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input))
    {
        sb.Append(Convert.ToString(b, 2));
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

You feed this a base64 string and get bits back. The problem is: this `Convert.ToString(b, 2)` omits leading zeroes causing the differences you see:

- 'A': `(0)1000001`
- '0': `(00)110000`

So some characters are reported as having 6 bits, others have 7. The hash is ultimately a byte array, and this is of fixed length: 32, times 8 = 256. Hashes are sometimes base64-encoded to ensure safe storage and transmission. This increases the size, as the characters have less entropy.

Data of 32 bytes is, when base64-encoded, at most 44 characters.

Comment: Thank you, I think I'm starting to understand. Does this mean my SQL Server data type should be `varchar(44)`? Something about that seems odd.

Comment: Yes. You could use a `varbinary(32)` if you want to shave off twelve bytes.

Comment: I see. So if I want the convenience of string comparison, I could use text, but if I want to save a little more space, I can use the binary directly. Any reason to use `varbinary(32)` over `binary(32)` we're dealing with fixed-length data?

Comment: Exactly. And no, I read your `varchar` and substituted `varbinary`. Of course it can be just `binary(32)`, shaving off another byte or two for its size.